# Property of functions over generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions, generating-functions

I know that if $f(x)=g(\frac{x}{1-x})$, then $f(\frac{x}{1+x})=g(x)$ when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are function.

When I read about generating functions , I saw that "Generating functions are not functions in the formal sense of a mapping from a domain to a codomain. Generating functions are sometimes called generating series" in [wiki.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)

Now assume that we have two generating function such that $W(x,y) = S (\frac{x}{1-x},\frac{y}{1-y})$ where $W= \frac{1}{1-(x+y)}$ and $S$ represent the smirnov words. Then the book says that $W(\frac{x}{1+x},\frac{y}{1+y})=S(x,y)$.

My question is that if generating functions are not actually function, then how do they satify the property of functions. Can you prove the foregoing relation about the generating functions ?

Comment: GFs are not _in general_ functions in that sense, but if they have a positive radius of convergence they are functions with a suitable domain.

Comment: @J.G. I think here they dont have positive radius, if you look at W, you ll realize it. Then how do  they satify ?

Comment: OK, could you link me to a formula for $S$? (Or better still, update your question to specify it.)

Comment: @J.G. [this link](https://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) page 205

Comment: In that case the domain on which the functions converge appears to be $x\ge0,\,y\ge0,\,x+y<1$.

Comment: @J.G. how did you determine that ? can you please write a clear answer

Comment: @J.G. whats more, can you please show me a link or available pdf about the info such that "GFs are not in general functions in that sense, but if they have a positive radius of convergence they are functions with a suitable domain"

Comment: This is by definition - if a formal power series converges in a certain domain, it, by definition, means the series defines a function on this domain. However, I can recommend "Lectures on generating functions" by Sergei K. Lando and "Generatingfunctionology" by Herbert S. Wilf (3rd edition)

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku I look at both book but could see the definition :( can you please explain how my power series converges in a certain domain, J.G.'s comment above says something, but I could not understand how he concluded. CAn you show me a general way to find that my generating function is converging and so it is a function there

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku by the way, thanks for your patience and effort. If you can edit your answer as to my last comment, i can accept it

Comment: The question of convergence is completely different from the one stated in your original post. Please, create a separate question for that one. In short, there are numerous criteria for convergence of series, they are routinely taught in calculus classes. You can find a section dedicated to the question of convergence of series in any calculus textbook. Look for something that applies to your specific case and apply it.

Answer (score 3):

Generating functions, are, in general, formal power series with coefficients from $\mathbb{R}$. Formal power series form a ring: you can add them component-wise, you can multiply them by constants, you can multiply them by other formal power series, since coefficient before each term of the resulting series is a finite sum:
$$a(z)b(z)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\cdot z^{k}\right) \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}b_{l} \cdot z^{l}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}$$

The functional composition of formal power series is well-defined as well, if in the expression $A(B)$ where $A, B$ are formal power series, $B$ has no term of degree 0 (otherwise in the resulting series coefficients are not finite sums anymore):
$$a(b(z))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\left(\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}b_{l}\cdot z^{l} \right)^{k}$$

The notation $W\left(\frac{x}{1-x},\frac{y}{1-y}\right)=S(x,y)$ means the formal power series $W(...)$ and $S(x,y)$ coincide in each term, and
$$W\left(\frac{x}{1-x},\frac{y}{1-y}\right)$$
should be understood as composition of formal power series:
$$\frac{x}{1-x}=x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}$$
(note that the term of degree 0 is not present).

You can also work with formal power series of several variables. Again, they are treated as ordered sets of coefficients, but these sets have several indices (power of $x$, power of $y$, power of $z$ etc.). Substitution, multiplication and summation are again defined component-wise. For instance, the formal power series defined by the function of two variables $1/(1-(x+y))$ is
$$\frac{1}{1-(x+y)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{k}y^{n-k}$$
Since $k+(n-k)=n$, the $n$-th "small" sum is homogeneous of total degree $n$, and you can't simplify the expression any further (however, you need to choose some convention by which you sort coefficients inside such series).

If two formal power series have intersecting domains of convergence, and define some functions on the intersection, the algebraic relations between these formal power series are the same as between their corresponding functions in the region of intersection.

Comment: I could not understand the relation between the property of functions is valid in genrating function, yes I know what W mean as summation formula, but how can we do the manipulation

Comment: What exact manipulation do you mean?

Comment: putting the inverse of x/(1-x) in place of x in both W and S, we can do it in functions but they are not in formal definition ,they are series

Comment: In the literature concerning generating functions, it is common practice to use functions as alias for their Taylor series, treated as formal power series. The difference is that, working with formal power series, we are not concerned with the question of convergence. $\frac{x}{1-x}$ means the formal power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}$. You substitute this formal power series into the one for $W(...,...)$, as described in the answer, then compute the coefficient before each monomial $x^{i}y^{j}$ in the resulting series.

Comment: if you look at the book and the page number above, you will see a statement "Now, since the inverse function of v/(1-v) is v/(1+v)...". So, my question is that how can wrting inverse work as it works over functions. It is my question, what you wrote in your answer is I already know

Comment: If two formal power series have intersecting domains of convergence, and define some functions on the intersection, the algebraic relations between these formal power series are the same as the algebraic relations between these functions. Since both $\frac{v}{1-v}$ and $\frac{v}{1+v}$ are analytic in the neighborhood of zero, their formal power series satisfy the same relations they do. You can check this directly by substituting one formal power series into another and calculating coefficients before terms of each degree.

Comment: The formal power series for $\frac{v}{1-v}$ is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v^{k}$, the formal power series for $\frac{v}{1+v}$ is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}v^{k}$, try substituting one into another and see what happens.

Comment: it is very hard to see it is really equal to "v" in summation formula, it goes to infinity and I couldnt see that the terms cancels each other except for v

Comment: Realize that $\left( v + v^2 + v^3 + ... \right)^{k}$ has __no terms of degree lower than $k$__. This means, when you substitute one series into another, for each degree $n$ you have only only $n$ terms containing the degree $n$. Group all contributions to each degree. You will obtain the series $0 + 1\cdot v + 0\cdot v^2 + 0\cdot v^{3} + ...$